# How to crop a image into several rectangular grids using imagemagick in nodejs

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-editing

I am using nodejs imagemagick module. Its is very difficult to find how i could split a give image into several rectangular grids(Just like in Instagram). How can this be achieved in nodejs ? Any examples will help me a lot ...
Official site gives only examples for CLI...